# What is the average product of the numbers drawn?

Tags: probability, average

There are 10 tickets in a box, each with a number on it. The average of those 10 numbers is zero. The average value of the squares of those numbers is 5.

(a). If you pick two tickets at random, WITH replacement, what is the average product of the numbers drawn?

(b). If you pick two tickets at random, WITHOUT replacement, what is the average product of the numbers drawn?

Answer (score 3):

Since there's now in my view an overly formal and an insufficiently formal answer, I'll offer what I see as the appropriate middle ground :-)

Let $a_k$ denote the $10$ numbers.

(a)

$$\sum_i\sum_j(a_ia_j)=\left(\sum_ia_i\right)\left(\sum_ja_j\right)=0\;.$$

The sum of all products is zero, so the average product is zero.

(b)

$$\sum_i\sum_{j\ne i}(a_ia_j)=\sum_i\sum_j(a_ia_j)-\sum_i(a_ia_i)=0-10\cdot5=-50\;.$$

The sum contains $10\cdot9=90$ products, so the average product is $\frac{-50}{90}=-\frac59$.

Comment: This is what we call a proof from the book.

Answer (score 1):

The average sum is zero and average value of squares is $5.$

Let the numbers be $-\sqrt{5}\mbox{  }$ $\mbox{  }5$ times and $\sqrt{5}$ $f$ times.

$a)$ Let first ticket be $\sqrt{5}$ and the second ticket can be $\pm$ with equal probability.  Average product $=0$

$b)$ If first number is $\sqrt{5}$. Second number can be positive with $\dfrac49$ probability and negative with $\dfrac59$ probability . Average product $=-5\times\dfrac19=-\dfrac59$

Similar case if the first number is $-\sqrt{5}$ and Average $=-\dfrac59$

So, the average product $=-\dfrac59$

Comment: The answer is right, but you seem to have assumed that the information given in the question is sufficient and thus you can simply calculate with one example. You need to add an argument for the information being sufficient. (Also, it wouldn't hurt to spell out the example more clearly -- you seem to be using the example of $5$ tickets with $+\sqrt5$ on them and 5 with $-\sqrt5$.)

Comment: So do I need to say that,  Let the numbers be $-\sqrt{5}\mbox{  }$ $\mbox{  }5$ times and $\sqrt{5}$ $f$ times.

Comment: That too, yes, but you also need to provide an argument why you can just assume some numbers instead of working with general numbers. This only works if we know that the answer is fully determined by the information provided in the question.

Comment: Do you assume the number to be -sqrt(5) and sqrt(5) because the average of those 10 numbers is zero and the average value of the squares of those numbers is 5? Also, I don't really understand for part (a). What if the second ticket that I chose is also sqrt(5). Isn't the average going to be sqrt(5) because (sqrt(5) + sqrt(5))/2 is equal to sqrt(5)? Sorry, I am a bit confused.

Comment: @ibuntu: In part (a), the average is zero because you're just as likely to choose a positive or negative number. This includes the possibility of drawing the same ticket again; that's just one of the five options that lead to a positive product, and is thus already accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=10$, this makes it simpler to type that index in LaTeX. (We cannot speak about a generalization...)

Let $\Omega_0$ be $\{1,2,\dots n\}$, we consider on it the uniform probability. 
The question deals with $\Omega =\Omega_0\times\Omega_0$, the set of all $(j,k)$, the case "with replacement", and with 
$\Omega'=\{\ (j,k)\in\Omega\ :\ j\ne k\ \}$, the case "without replacement".

We consider the random variable $A:\Omega_0\to \Bbb R$, $j\to A(j)=a_j$, and the induced variables $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$, $X(j,k)=A(j)A(k)$ on $\Omega$, respectively $X' :\Omega'\to\Bbb R$, given by the same formula $X'(j,k)=A(j)A(k)$, but the domain of definition is smaller.

The problem gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb E[A] &=\frac 1n\sum_{1\le j\le n }a_j=0\ ,\\
\operatorname{Var}[A] &=\frac 1n\sum_{1\le j\le n }(a_j-0)^2=5\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(So $\sum a_j^2=5n$ to have it simpler.)

Let us start to solve the problem.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb E[X] 
&=\frac 1{|\Omega|}\sum_{(j,k)\in\Omega }X(j,k)
=\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{1\le j,k\le n }a_ja_k
=\frac 1{n^2}
\left(\sum_{1\le j\le n }a_j\right)
\left(\sum_{1\le k\le n }a_k\right)
\\
&=(\ \Bbb E A\ )^2 =0^2 =0\ ,
\\[2mm]
\Bbb E[X'] 
&=\frac 1{|\Omega'|}\sum_{(j,k)\in\Omega }X'(j,k)
=\frac 1{n(n-1)}\sum_{\substack{1\le j,k\le n\\j\ne k}}a_ja_k\\
&=\frac 1{n(n-1)}
\sum_{1\le j,k\le n}a_ja_k 
-
\frac 1{n(n-1)}
 \sum_{\substack{1\le j,k\le n\\j=k}}a_ja_k 
\\
&=
\frac 1{n(n-1)}
\left[ \ 
\left(\sum_{1\le j\le n }a_j\right)
\left(\sum_{1\le k\le n }a_k\right)
-
\left(\sum_{1\le j\le n }a_j^2\right)
\ \right]
\\
&=
\frac n{n-1}(\Bbb E A)^2
-
\frac 1{n-1}\operatorname{Var}[A]
\\
&=
-
\frac 1{n-1}\operatorname{Var}[A]
=-\frac 59\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(Sorry about the "probability space bureaucracy"... Somehow i felt the obligation to do it.)